# Код для JS таймера

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть бд mysql в которой содержится таблица заказов.

В этой таблице есть столбец, время создания 16:52.

Как сделать js таймер, чтобы просчитывало сколько времени назад был создан заказ?
Может быть, у кого-то есть примеры?

Comment: вы хоть что-то пытались написать?

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ - получить Unix Timestamp, используя соответствующую [функцию](https://database.guide/unix_timestamp-examples-mysql/) в MySQL. Если от этого числа отнять актуальный timestamp, получится время в секундах с момента создания записии в бд. Получить текущий timestamp в JavaScript можно так:

```
Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
```

Далее можно применить готовый код из [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5517836/7388307) вопроса